# Displaying Custom Post Types In "At A Glance" Meta Box

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, dashboard

I found the following snippet will displays the number of Custom Post Types published in Dashboard's At A Glance widget, like this:

[image: At A Glance]

Is there a way to turn that "81 Wrestlers" text to a link to the post types list. Here's the code:

```
add_filter( 'dashboard_glance_items', 'custom_glance_items', 10, 1 );
function custom_glance_items( $items = array() ) {
    $post_types = array( 'wrestler' );
    foreach( $post_types as $type ) {
        if( ! post_type_exists( $type ) ) continue;
        $num_posts = wp_count_posts( $type );
        if( $num_posts ) {
            $published = intval( $num_posts->publish );
            $post_type = get_post_type_object( $type );
            $text = _n( '%s ' . $post_type->labels->singular_name, '%s ' . $post_type->labels->name, $published, 'your_textdomain' );
            $text = sprintf( $text, number_format_i18n( $published ) );
            if ( current_user_can( $post_type->cap->edit_posts ) ) {
                $items[] = sprintf( '%2$s', $type, $text ) . "\n";
            } else {
                $items[] = sprintf( '%2$s', $type, $text ) . "\n";
            }
        }
    }
    return $items;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I used this code to only display "wrestler" post type & it worked. I mixed mine & Pieter Goosen's code to get this out:

```
add_filter( 'dashboard_glance_items', 'custom_glance_items', 10, 1 );
function custom_glance_items( $items = array() ) {
    $post_types = array( 'wrestler' );
    foreach( $post_types as $type ) {
        if( ! post_type_exists( $type ) ) continue;
        $num_posts = wp_count_posts( $type );
        if( $num_posts ) {
            $published = intval( $num_posts->publish );
            $post_type = get_post_type_object( $type );
            $text = _n( '%s ' . $post_type->labels->singular_name, '%s ' . $post_type->labels->name, $published, 'your_textdomain' );
            $text = sprintf( $text, number_format_i18n( $published ) );
            if ( current_user_can( $post_type->cap->edit_posts ) ) {
            $output = '<a href="edit.php?post_type=' . $post_type->name . '">' . $text . '</a>';
                echo '<li class="post-count ' . $post_type->name . '-count">' . $output . '</li>';
            } else {
            $output = '<span>' . $text . '</span>';
                echo '<li class="post-count ' . $post_type->name . '-count">' . $output . '</li>';
            }
        }
    }
    return $items;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Here is the function that I use to display CPT in the "At a glance" widget

```
add_action( 'dashboard_glance_items', 'cpad_at_glance_content_table_end' );
function cpad_at_glance_content_table_end() {
    $args = array(
        'public' => true,
        '_builtin' => false
    );
    $output = 'object';
    $operator = 'and';

    $post_types = get_post_types( $args, $output, $operator );
    foreach ( $post_types as $post_type ) {
        $num_posts = wp_count_posts( $post_type->name );
        $num = number_format_i18n( $num_posts->publish );
        $text = _n( $post_type->labels->singular_name, $post_type->labels->name, intval( $num_posts->publish ) );
        if ( current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ) {
            $output = '<a href="edit.php?post_type=' . $post_type->name . '">' . $num . ' ' . $text . '</a>';
            echo '<li class="post-count ' . $post_type->name . '-count">' . $output . '</li>';
        }
    }
}
```

This make the text clickable as link. Hope this helps

Comment: But it's showing all the custom post types, and I only wanna display "Wrestler" post type.

Comment: I edited your code & mixed it with mine & it worked :) Thanks!

Comment: @Hardeep Asrani glad I could help. Would be great if you could add your code as an answer.

Comment: @PieterGoosen Probably a long shot, but I'm looking at getting the "At a glance" box to display the right Dashicon ( https://developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons/ ). Any idea?

Comment: This really helped... Now any idea how I can display them with their own icons? I'm trying to add the dashicon class in the output ... `$output = '<a class="' . $post_type->menu_icon . '" href="edit.php?post_type=' . $post_type->name . '">' . $num . ' ' . $text . '</a>';` ... but there are styles that override it, so I tried adding this style : `#dashboard_right_now li a::before, #dashboard_right_now li > span::before { content: initial; }` ... but that overrides the dashicon class style. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

For all future occurrences, of adding custom post types to the 'At a Glance' box, the following code worked for me in WordPress 4.6.1. And it may work for others.

```
// Add custom taxonomies and custom post types counts to dashboard
    add_action( 'dashboard_glance_items', 'cpt_to_at_a_glance' );
function cpt_to_at_a_glance() {
        // Custom post types counts
        $post_types = get_post_types( array( '_builtin' => false ), 'objects' );
        foreach ( $post_types as $post_type ) {
            $num_posts = wp_count_posts( $post_type->name );
            $num = number_format_i18n( $num_posts->publish );
            $text = _n( $post_type->labels->singular_name, $post_type->labels->name, $num_posts->publish );
            if ( current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ) {
                $num = '<li class="post-count"><a href="edit.php?post_type=' . $post_type->name . '">' . $num . ' ' . $text . '</a></li>';
            }
            echo $num;
        }
    }
```

All credit goes to the [following author](https://clicknathan.com/web-design/add-custom-post-types-to-wordpress-at-a-glance-dashboard/)

Answer (score 0):

In code you posted I can't really understand whats the point of:

```
if ( current_user_can( $post_type->cap->edit_posts ) ) {
  $items[] = sprintf( '%2$s', $type, $text ) . "\n";
} else {
  $items[] = sprintf( '%2$s', $type, $text ) . "\n";
}
```

I.E. if the current user can edit the post type do something, otherwise do same thing...

I guess you want to show the link to posts list if the current user can edit post type (just like WordPress does for pages and posts).

In that case your code becomes:

```
function custom_glance_items( $items = array() ) {
  $post_types = array( 'wrestler' );
  foreach( $post_types as $type ) {
    if( ! post_type_exists( $type ) ) continue;
    $num_posts = wp_count_posts( $type );
    if( $num_posts ) {
      $published = intval( $num_posts->publish );
      $post_type = get_post_type_object( $type );
      $text = _n(
        '%s ' . $post_type->labels->singular_name,
        '%s ' . $post_type->labels->name,
        $published,
        'your_textdomain'
      );
      $text = sprintf( $text, number_format_i18n( $published ) );

      // show post type list id user can edit the post type,
      // otherwise just swho the name and the count
      if ( current_user_can( $post_type->cap->edit_posts ) ) {
        $edit_url = add_query_arg( array('post_type' => $type),  admin_url('edit.php') );
        $items[] = sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', $edit_url, $text ) . "\n";
      } else {
        $items[] = $text . "\n";
      }

    } // end if( $num_posts )
  } // end foreach
  return $items;
}
```

Comment: Not working in my case.